# Ionic android defaut emulator

Tags: ionic-framework, android-emulator, emulation

I have a multiple emulators (AVD, Genymotion,..)

When I run : `ionic emulate android`, it runs the Android AVD emulator.

How can I set Genymotion as default emulator ? is there any settings to adjuste or an option to add to the command ?

Answer (score 0):

First, start genymotion virtual device. Then try

```
ionic run android
```

In case of error, in the vm selection window in genymotion, you can change the path to the android sdk. Change this to be the path that you have set.

Answer (score 0):

To choose an specific device to deploy you app, you should start genymotion first. Right after emulator is up run the command `adb devices` on terminal and you should see the devices connected to the computer, including the emulators like the image.[image]

Then simply run the command:

```
ionic run android
```

or

```
ionic run android --target emulator-5554
```